# On my leisure vs At my leisure vs In my leisure

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct and why?

> **on my leisure** vs **at my leisure**

Prepositions are always confusing to me. I know that they are based on context apart from its general meaning. I get confused about it.

Generally **on** is used to denote something situated at a surface, and 
**at** to pinpoint a location or time. But is what is the case here?

Additionally, what about *in my leisure*?

Comment: Those generalities are just one of many valid usages of those words. There are also a great many idiomatic expressions and phrasal verbs to consider; for example: _on the telephone, on the radio, on the panel, on the mark, on the list, on drugs, on a diet, on the house, on tour, on the train, right on time,_ and _eyes on me_  – none of those expressions have anything to do with "something situated upon a surface".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leisure) has

> **at (one's) leisure**
>
> Done according to one's own convenience or comfort.
>   *There is no time limit to the exam, so please complete it at your leisure.*

---

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/at_leisure) has this

> **at leisure**
>
> **1** Not occupied; free.
>   *the rest of the day can be spent at leisure*
>
> **2** In an unhurried manner.
>   *the poems were left for others to read at leisure*

---

However, a different preposition is used here:

> I play steel drums in my leisure time.

But I don't know of any usage using the preposition "**on**".

Comment: In my leisure and At my leisure have the same meaning?

Comment: No, the last quote is clearly different, where the preposition "in" is used with "time", and "leisure" is a noun adjunct.

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge, what's noun adjunct? Do you mean if we use 'leisure' with 'time'  we should use" in my leisure time"? Is that so?

Comment: It is a noun used like an adjective, to qualify a noun. For example in "chicken soup", the "chicken" is a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).